# Citreon C3 1.6 Auto wont crank on key to start, but starts with key in ignition and a direct 12v feed to the starter any clues? had new battery

Tags: starting, citroen-c3

I had to replace a faulty battery as had to start via jump leads, ran sweet. switched off to move and close garage door, then would not re start. On replacing with a new battery car would not crank from the new battery or jump. New battery tested and OK. Had a quick look and cleaned the 2 chassis earths. Used a 12v probe from the battery direct to the starter, engine cranked and fired up and ran sweetly. drove car 3 miles to home address and guess what will only start using the 12v probe method.

Any clues as to what the issue is with getting a signal to the starter that the probe cures as each time I use the probe I will have to remove lot of components to gain access?

Comment: When you say “direct to the starter” do you mean the small connection to the starter solenoid?

Comment: Citreon or Citroen 1.6? If its a Citroen with a conventional starting circuit, the ignition switch turned to START sends a 12v start signal to the starter.  Examine and measure the small wire on the starter when ign is turned to Start.  Be aware of the engine cranking up so disconnecting a fuel pump fuse, ignition coils or its wiring will prevent the engine from firing up while testing.